# Unable to Publish artifacts to file share in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are trying to setup CI/CD for a winform app developed using DotNet core 6. We have setup the build pipeline and it's producing the correct set of artifacts but the problem is we are unable to publish these artifacts to network file share drive (DFS server). While connecting to network file share we are getting error Incorrect username or password. Do we need a service account which would connect to network file share ? If there is a service account needed we don't see any option in release pipeline under which task in Azure Devops we need to pass username and password as the Publish artifact task allow us to define the network location without using any credentials. Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Are you using a private agent or the Microsoft hosted agents?

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need a service account which would connect to network file share
> ?

Seems like you asked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/925315/unable-to-publish-pipeline-artifact-to-network-fil.html) too. For a self-hosted agent, yes, we need a service account that can connect to the network file share.

Basically, you can try to setup the agent with the account which has the correct permission (write permission) to access the network share. (specify the account as the agent service account).

Alternately, you can use [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy the artifacts to the network share. In the task you can specify the username and password to access the network share.

[image]

Comment: @Sunny Sharma Have you resolved the issue by the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can be accomplish through service principal/agent that has write permission to the drive. You can then create scripts in the build pipeline to transfer the file to the Azure storage account blob container.